# how can i put a carousel in bot.on with bot framework?

Tags: frameworks, botframework, bots

I have a chatbot with bot framework and I want to have this for my first message in **bot.on** but I don't know how can I do it.

*Choose your language / Choisissez votre langue :*

(img "flag french")  |  (img "flag english")  |  (img "flag spanish") 
  button "français"   |      button "english"     |   button "spanish"

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach((identity) => {
            if (identity.id == message.address.bot.id) {
                CODE HERE
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Should I use a carousel with 3 card ? but I don't know how to do it in **bot.on**

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible in v3. Is this a new bot? If so, I would recommend using v4 as v3 is being phased out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I find it !

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach((identity) => {
            if (identity.id == message.address.bot.id && message.source != 'skypeforbusiness') {
                console.log(message);
                bot.send(new builder.Message()
                    .address(message.address)
                    .text('Choose your language :')
                );
                setTimeout(function () {
                    bot.send(new builder.Message()
                        .address(message.address)
                        .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
                        .attachments([
                            new builder.HeroCard()
                                .title()
                                .subtitle()
                                .text()
                                .images([builder.CardImage.create(null, '')])
                                .buttons([
                                    builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "English", "English")
                                ]),
                            new builder.HeroCard()
                                .title()
                                .subtitle()
                                .text()
                                .images([builder.CardImage.create(null, '')])
                                .buttons([
                                    builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "Français")
                                ]),
                            new builder.HeroCard()
                                .title()
                                .subtitle()
                                .text()
                                .images([builder.CardImage.create(null, '')])
                                .buttons([
                                    builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "Español", "Español")
                                ])
                        ])
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```