# BOT Framework Carousel of Images for Teams Channel

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am using MS document for Displaying Carousel of Images.
Code that I used:-

```
var heroCard1 = new HeroCard
                {
                    Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources", "Step1.png")) },
                };
                var heroCard2 = new HeroCard
                {
                    Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources", "Step1.png")) },
                };               


                var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(heroCard1.ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(heroCard2.ToAttachment());
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

I am not getting Carousel of Images. instead I am getting empty carousel.
But when i use herocards indivisually they work fine.
Please help me to find solution ? Thanks In advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Form Carousel of hero cards in bot framework v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082949/how-to-form-carousel-of-hero-cards-in-bot-framework-v4)

Comment: [how can i put a carousel in bot.on with bot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219848/how-can-i-put-a-carousel-in-bot-on-with-bot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the sample code for carousel images in BOT framework*

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach((identity) => {
            if (identity.id == message.address.bot.id && message.source != 'skypeforbusiness') {
                console.log(message);
                bot.send(new builder.Message()
                    .address(message.address)
                    .text('Choose your language :')
                );
                setTimeout(function () {
                    bot.send(new builder.Message()
                        .address(message.address)
                        .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
                        .attachments([
                            new builder.HeroCard()
                                .title()
                                .subtitle()
                                .text()
                                .images([builder.CardImage.create(null, '')])
                                .buttons([
                                    builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "English", "English")
                                ]),
                            new builder.HeroCard()
                                .title()
                                .subtitle()
                                .text()
                                .images([builder.CardImage.create(null, '')])
                                .buttons([
                                    builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "Français")
                                ]),
                            new builder.HeroCard()
                                .title()
                                .subtitle()
                                .text()
                                .images([builder.CardImage.create(null, '')])
                                .buttons([
                                    builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "Español", "Español")
                                ])
                        ])
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*You refer the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59084306/15969833) thread for information.*